# Internet slows down after short period of use

Tags: networking

I have a Gigabyte brix gb-bxbt-2807 and have recently started to use Ubuntu 18.04 rather than Windows 10. Everything seemed to work well for a while but I noticed that online music seemed to be dropping out. I discovered that my download speed had dropped to .2 meg After a reboot this went back up 11 meg. This keeps happening but is only affecting this PC not other equipment. I am using WiFi and have't tried a wired connection. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable power saving for your wifi device. Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install wireless-tools
sudo iw dev wlp1s0 set power_save off
```

Note that your wireless device might be something other than `wlp1s0` like above. You can run this command to list them out:

```
 iw dev
```

Also note that once the computer is reboot or suspended that power saving will be enabled again. It's also possible that connecting a charger will cause power saving to be turned on or off as well.

If you want to permanently disable wifi power saving see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/629039/disabling-power-save-option-on-wifi-device) which basically says create `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-wifi-powersave.rules` and put this contents into it:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", KERNEL=="wlan*" RUN+="/sbin/iw dev %k set power_save off"
```

(Note I have modified the above command to use `/sbin/iw` which is where Ubuntu stores the `iw` command instead of `/usr/bin/iw` which some other Linux distributions use)